# JPA save BigDecimal as integer in Database

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this field in the database:

```
ITEMCOST    NUMERIC (13)    DEFAULT 0  NOT NULL
```

In JAVA, the field in the Entity is defined like this:

```
@Column(name = "ITEMCOST")
private BigDecimal itemCost;
```

The values are stored in the database as integer. Where the last two digits are the decimal values. like this:

- DB **100** means 1.00
- DB **250**  means 2.50
- etc

What I want is when I read the Entity the value is loaded like that. 
If the value in the database is 357 the BigDeciamal should have the value  "3.57". And when I save that entity, the value should be converted again as INT.

Comment: have you looked into JPA converters?

Comment: Here's an article describing what @PrasadMarne is talking about https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the comments say you should use an Attribute converter.

Please find a description here https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

It could look like this:

```
@Converter
public class BigDecimalConverter implements AttributeConverter<BigDecimal, Long> {

  @Override
  public Long convertToDatabaseColumn(BigDecimal value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return value.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).longValue();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public BigDecimal convertToEntityAttribute(Long value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return new BigDecimal(value).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in your entity

```
@Convert(converter = BigDecimalConverter.class)
@Column(name = "ITEMCOST")
private BigDecimal itemCost;
```